# Oracle CTE performance issue

Tags: oracle

In order to make the comparison case insensitive but display correctly we written below query

```
WITH VALUE_LIST
     AS (SELECT *
           FROM (SELECT m1."ASSIGNMENT" col#0,
                        m1."ASSIGNEE_NAME" col#1,
                        ROW_NUMBER ()
                        OVER (
                           PARTITION BY m1."ASSIGNMENT", m1."ASSIGNEE_NAME"
                           ORDER BY m1."ASSIGNMENT", m1."ASSIGNEE_NAME")
                           ROW_INDEX
                   FROM PROBSUMMARYM1 m1)
          WHERE ROW_INDEX = 1)
SELECT vl.col#0, vl.col#1, GROUPED_DATA.CNT
  FROM (  SELECT UPPER (m1."ASSIGNMENT") col#0,
                 UPPER (m1."ASSIGNEE_NAME") col#1,
                 COUNT (*) CNT
            FROM PROBSUMMARYM1 m1
        GROUP BY UPPER (m1."ASSIGNMENT"), UPPER (m1."ASSIGNEE_NAME")
        ORDER BY UPPER (m1."ASSIGNMENT") ASC, UPPER (m1."ASSIGNEE_NAME") ASC)
       GROUPED_DATA,
       VALUE_LIST vl
 WHERE     (   GROUPED_DATA.col#0 = UPPER (vl.col#0)
            OR (GROUPED_DATA.col#0 IS NULL AND vl.col#0 IS NULL))
       AND (   GROUPED_DATA.col#1 = UPPER (vl.col#1)
            OR (GROUPED_DATA.col#1 IS NULL AND vl.col#1 IS NULL))
```

But with the group numbers growing the performance degrade significantly. 
Is there any query can get the same query but no performance issue?

Comment: Have you tried a function based index `CREATE INDEX somename ON PROBSUMMARYM1( UPPER ("ASSIGNMENT"), UPPER ("ASSIGNEE_NAME"))` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
SELECT ASSIGNMENT, 
       ASSIGNEE_NAME,
       CNT
FROM (
  SELECT m1."ASSIGNMENT", 
         m1."ASSIGNEE_NAME",
         row_number() OVER (
               PARTITION BY m1."ASSIGNMENT", m1."ASSIGNEE_NAME"
               ORDER BY m1."ASSIGNMENT", m1."ASSIGNEE_NAME"
         )  As ROW_INDEX,
         COUNT(*) OVER (
               PARTITION BY UPPER (m1."ASSIGNMENT"), 
                            UPPER (m1."ASSIGNEE_NAME")
         ) As CNT
  FROM PROBSUMMARYM1 m1
)
WHERE ROW_INDEX = 1
;
```

As a side note, this part of the query in the quuestion:

```
WITH VALUE_LIST
     AS (SELECT *
           FROM (SELECT m1."ASSIGNMENT" col#0,
                        m1."ASSIGNEE_NAME" col#1,
                        ROW_NUMBER ()
                        OVER (
                           PARTITION BY m1."ASSIGNMENT", m1."ASSIGNEE_NAME"
                           ORDER BY m1."ASSIGNMENT", m1."ASSIGNEE_NAME")
                           ROW_INDEX
                   FROM PROBSUMMARYM1 m1)
          WHERE ROW_INDEX = 1)
```

is a very sophisticated version of this one:

```
SELECT DISTINCT m1."ASSIGNMENT" col#0, 
                m1."ASSIGNEE_NAME" col#1
FROM PROBSUMMARYM1 m1
```